# Post hoc analysis after meta regression

Tags: r, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am running a meta-analysis using **metafor** R package. I am comparing studies on a continuous variable, that can be synthetized by the mean. Such studies can be grouped in three blocks. I used a meta regression, e.g.

```
dat <- escalc(measure="MN", mi=mean, sdi=sd, ni=num, data=dbtemp)
res <- rma(yi, vi, mods =~ factor(group), data=dat)
```

I know that I can know whether group is significant or not. But how can I assess whether each level within group is significant from the other. I.e., how I can perform multiple comparisons (post hoc analysis) within a meta - analysis context?

Comment: If group is dummy coded, can you just change the reference category?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `anova(res, L=c(...))` to obtain contrasts. For a three-level factor (with levels 1, 2, and 3), the model will include two dummy variables, contrasting level 2 vs 1 and level 3 vs 1. So you already have those contrasts. With `anova(res, L=c(0,-1,1))` you can get the contrast of level 3 vs 2. If you want all three contrasts at the same time, use:

```
anova(res, L=rbind(c(0,1,0),c(0,0,1),c(0,-1,1)))
```

You can also use the `glht()` function from the `multcomp` package for this:

```
summary(glht(res, linfct=rbind(c(0,1,0),c(0,0,1),c(0,-1,1))), test=adjusted("none"))
```

By changing the `test` argument, you can obtain multiplicity adjusted p-values (see `help(summary.glht)` for more details).

I also have an extensive discussion/illustration related to these types of analyses on the `metafor` package website. See:

http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:testing_factors_lincoms