# Easy post-hoc tests when meta-analyzing with the `metafor` package in r

Tags: r, multiple-comparisons, meta-analysis, post-hoc, meta-regression

I am conducting meta-analysis using `metafor` in R.
I would like to compare among 7 levels in a factor (i.e. different types of treatments).

```
fit <- rma (yi, vi, mods = type_of_treatment - 1, data = dat)
fit
```

I found several websites explaining how to compare among levels by using `anova()` (e.g., [Post hoc analysis after meta regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182079/post-hoc-analysis-after-meta-regression) & http://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:testing_factors_lincoms?s[]=anova); however, because I have seven levels (i.e. seven different types of treatments), doing comparisons by myself is  pretty trouble same.

I tried `glht()` in the multcomp package, but the following command provides error.

```
summary(glht(fit, linfct = mcp(~type_of_treatment = "Tukey"))
```

I would really appreciate if you could let me know if there is any easy way to conduct a pairwise comparison among levels, like the `glht()` or `emmeans()` for lm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the `contrMat()` function. Something like this should work:

```
summary(glht(fit, linfct=cbind(contrMat(rep(1,7), type="Tukey"))), test=adjusted("none"))
```

You might want to consider an adjustment for multiple testing though. See `help(summary.glht)` for some options.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for!! Thank you so much, @Wolfgang. I hope you have a great day today.

Comment: The results for post-hoc testing appear to depend on which factor level I set as the reference level. For example, I am conducting post-hoc testing for an meta-analysis with "continent" as the moderator. When the reference level is North America (as compared to Asia, for example), I get different results for the comparisons that involve the intercept. This makes sense, as the intercept estimate is the meta-analytic estimate at the reference level, while the predictor estimates are beta weights.

Comment: It doesn't seem correct to run a post-hoc comparison between an intercept and a beta weight, yet that's what glht is doing here. Shouldn't the test be between the the meta-analytic estimate for each factor level (i.e., intercept + factor level 2 beta weight vs. intercept + factor level 3 beta weight)? @Wolfgang

Comment: Did you remove the intercept like the OP did?

Comment: @Wolfgang Ah, I missed it. That makes so much more sense. Thank you!